# Using a column in a join expression without using it in the group by statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select c.id, c.fname, c.lname, d.phoneList
  from customers c
  left outer join
       (
        select listagg(telNo, ',') within group (order by telNo) as phoneList
          from customerPhones 
         group by p.telNo
       ) d 
   on (c.id = d.id)
```

On the above query, i am getting the following error on the statement `c.id = d.id`

```
ORA-00904 "d.id" invalid identifier.
```

It only works if i include it in the select statement and meaning that  need to include it in the group by statement. Is there any way i can use d.id without having to include it in the group by statement?

Comment: But you only select phone numbers in d, how could you have a d.id?

Comment: `ID` column must be present in the select list of the outer join query

Comment: @ziggy Sorry, now I see, outer join... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simplify to this?

```
SQL> select * from customers;

        ID FNAME                LNAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 John                 Smith
         2 Joe                  Bloggs

SQL> select * from customerphones;

        ID TELNO
---------- --------------------
         1 0123456789
         1 0207983498
         2 0124339848
         2 09348374834
         2 02387694364

SQL> select c.id, c.fname, c.lname, listagg(telNo, ',') within group (order by telNo) as phoneList
  2    from customers c left outer join customerphones p on p.id = c.id
  3   group by c.id, c.fname, c.lname
  4  /

        ID FNAME                LNAME                PHONELIST
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
         1 John                 Smith                0123456789,0207983498
         2 Joe                  Bloggs               0124339848,02387694364,0934837
                                                     4834
```